# Entity Framework only saving last row (master details)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

My project is c# Windows Application, I am using Entity Framework 5 and .net 4.5.

I have Rooms and Beds module which you can add, edit and delete Room(s) and/or bed(s)

on my Form I have a field for RoomNo and Station, also Add and Delete button to add/delete bed(s) to datagridview

```
DB Structure

Rooms (table)
PK_Rooms
FK_Station
RoomNo

Beds (table)
PK_Beds
FK_Rooms
BedNo
FullRoomNo (concat only of Roomno and Bedno)
RoomStatus
```

below is my Add Method to add the room and beds to DB

```
M3dEntities m3d = new M3dEntities();
rooms rooms = new rooms();
beds beds = new beds();

string RoomNo = RoomNoTxt.Text;
        int  StationID = Int32.Parse(StationCmb.SelectedValue.ToString());

        var roomnoexist = from g in m3d.rooms
                          where g.RoomNo == RoomNo
                          select g;

        if (roomnoexist.Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Room No. Already Exist!");
        }
        else
        {
            rooms.RoomNo = RoomNo;
            rooms.FK_Stations = StationID;

            m3d.rooms.AddObject(rooms);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in BedsDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            beds.Bedno = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            beds.FullRoomNo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            beds.RoomStatus = "Available";
            m3d.beds.AddObject(beds);
        }

        m3d.SaveChanges();
```

(Ex: add room 1201 with 4 beds)
Only last row of bed is saved to DB.

My Questions:

1. Why only save the last row?
2. How to save all rows to beds?
3. How can i do it for Edit Method (To add another bed or delete bed on the current room)?

Comment: What is the `m3d.beds.AddObject` method?

Comment: Follow this msdn article step by step and you will learn more about entity framework and master-detail. [Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

Comment: You should create new `beds` objects inside the loop. You're reusing one object now. Also, do yourself a favor and use singular names for classes/objects and plural names for collections.

Comment: thank you very much @GertArnold, this fixed my concern on saving all rows on beds.. however can you give me an idea how to do my 3rd question? thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `beds beds = new beds();` instruction inside your `foreach` statement like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in BedsDataGridView.Rows)
{
     beds beds = new beds(); // Here is its place.
     beds.Bedno = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     beds.FullRoomNo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     beds.RoomStatus = "Available";
     m3d.beds.AddObject(beds);
}
```

Wihtout that you are always oiverriden the last instance of `beds` which end up containing your last row and save only that row.

**Side note:** to gain some performance use `AddRange` if you are inserting multiple objects once like this:

```
var bedsCollection = new List<beds>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in BedsDataGridView.Rows)
{
     beds beds = new beds(); // Here is its place.
     beds.Bedno = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     beds.FullRoomNo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     beds.RoomStatus = "Available";
     bedsCollection.Add(beds); // update the collection not the DbSet
}

m3d.beds.AddRange(bedsCollection);
m3d.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you very much CodeNotFound! you saved me on my problem. However my next problem is on my Question #3. Can you give me idea on how to do it? Thanks again very much :)

Comment: The question #3 need the code already written to be shown and where yoy stick from. Please create another thread for that and I will help you there. If you think this answer satisfied you then accept it as an answer.

Comment: Anyway if you need to remove a bed just get the bed to be removed and do this : `m3d.beds.Remove(beds);`

Comment: yeah I'm satisfied on the resolution, will post another thread for my question #3.. Thanks again for the help..

Comment: Hi @CodeNotFound, below is the new thread for my question #3, hope you can help me.. thanks much :) 

[Entity Framework - how to save multiple changes (add, update, delete) to DB (Master detail)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364644/entity-framework-how-to-save-multiple-changes-add-update-delete-to-db-mas)