# Entity Framework - how to save multiple changes (add, update, delete) to DB (Master detail)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

My project is Windows Application c#, I am using Entity Framework 5 and .net 4.5.

I have Rooms and Beds module which you can add, edit and delete Room(s) and/or bed(s)

on my Form I have a field for RoomNo and Station, also Add and Delete button to add/delete bed(s) to datagridview, then Save button to save the Room and list of beds to DB

```
DB Structure

Rooms (table)
PK_Rooms
FK_Station
RoomNo

Beds (table)
PK_Beds
FK_Rooms
BedNo
FullRoomNo (concat only of Roomno and Bedno)
RoomStatus
```

I already implemented the "AddRoom" method which will create new Room and list of beds.

my question is how can i implement "EditRoom" method which will detect changes on the beds (added a new bed, AND/OR edited a bed number, AND/OR deleted a bed) and save it to DB?

To have a better understanding to my concern please see previous thread, which also has the AddRoom Method > 
[Entity Framework only saving last row (master details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361840/entity-framework-only-saving-last-row-master-details)

**Edit:**
here is my code to EditRoom method

```
        M3dEntities m3d = new M3dEntities();
        rooms rooms = new rooms();
        beds beds = new beds();
        string RoomNo = RoomNoTxt.Text;
        int StationID = Int32.Parse(StationCmb.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int _SelectedPKRoom = Int32.Parse(SelectedPKRoom);
        rooms = m3d.rooms.First(x => x.PK_Rooms == _SelectedPKRoom);
        {
            rooms.RoomNo = RoomNo;
            rooms.FK_Stations = StationID;
        }


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in BedsDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            beds = new beds();
            beds.Bedno = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            beds.FullRoomNo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            beds.RoomStatus = "Available";
            m3d.beds.AddObject(beds);
            m3d.beds.DeleteObject(beds);
        }

        m3d.SaveChanges();
```

the problem with this code is only room are being updated :(

Comment: Can you show us the `EditRoom` method you have started please?

Comment: [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)  This step-by-step walkthrough shows how to bind entities to WinForms controls in a “master-detail" form.

Comment: @RezaAghaei will try your suggestion. Ill update you if i got it working :) thanks

Comment: @CodeNotFound, included the EditRoom method on the thread bro. thanks

Comment: @Henry you are welcome, the article guides you to do master-detail easily and correctly.

Comment: @RezaAghaei that is what exactly i am looking for.. now all i need to do is to refactor my codes to do the same technique.. thank you for the info. please post it as an answer and i will tag it as accepted answer.. thank you very much bro..

Answer (score 0):

This is one Way, I hope it helps you

```
              var room= (from g in m3d.rooms
                      where g.RoomNo == RoomNo
                      select g).FirstOrDefault(); //Take an objecto room to modify 
    room.FK_Stations = StationID;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in BedsDataGridView.Rows)
   {

      int Bedno = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

      var bedsChanged= (from g in m3d.beds
                      where g.bedno== Bedno
                      select g).FirstOrDefault(); 

      bedsChanged.FullRoomNo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      bedsChanged.RoomStatus = "Available";

    }
     m3d.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer bro, but as indicated on the problem, the beds may have additional row and/or removal of existing row, and/or updated fields on the row.